# Converting .htaccess syntax to nginx config

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, silverstripe

I have moved my Silverstripe project from apache to nginx.
I see on the Silverstripe site

```
  RewriteRule .* framework/main.php?url=%1 [QSA]
```

is converted like this

```
    try_files $uri /framework/main.php?url=$uri&$query_string;
```

and it works fine. 
Following this, I wanted to convert this line to nginx:

```
RewriteRule .* dynamiccache/cache-main.php?url=%1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

I already tried in this way:

```
try_files $uri /dynamiccache/cache-main.php?url=$uri&$query_string;
```

It sort of works but not properly. Where is my mistake and how can I fix it?
Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: "It sort of works but not properly" what's the problem or error?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use [silverstripe-dynamiccache](https://github.com/tractorcow/silverstripe-dynamiccache)?

If so, you may be able to repurpose the Nginx config files from the [staticpublisher repo](https://github.com/silverstripe-labs/silverstripe-staticpublishqueue#nginx). Although the two projects handle cache file generation in different ways, the actual rewrites should be very similar.